# How to calculate for return period quantile estimation for flood frequency analysis using GEV and L-moments?

Tags: r, quantile, frequency-analysis, probability-distribution, goodness-of-fit

We have already tried the distribution fitting of GEV with L-moments on sample data provided in the extRemes package (Potomac River data), and we have obtained our location, scale, and shape parameters. We do not know how to proceed in goodness-of-fit testing and quantile estimation for 5-, 10-, and 20- year return periods. Any tips and suggestions to our problems would be of great help for the progress of our thesis.

```
data("Potomac")
fevd(Flow, Potomac, type = c("GEV"), method = c("Lmoments"), 106)
fitevd = fevd(Flow, Potomac, type = c("GEV"), method = c("Lmoments"), 106)
df = pevd(Potomac$Flow, loc = 8.693596e+04, scale = 4.135809e+04, 
      shape = 2.164866e-01, threshold = 1, lambda = 1, type = c("GEV"), 
      lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
ci(fitevd, alpha = 0.05, type = c("return.level"), return.period = 2, which.par, R = 502)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please only share code by pasting it in as plain text and **don't** share images of code as it makes it very difficult for people to help you. If you share what you've tried so far then people will be willing to help. Thanks.

Comment: This is noted. I apologize as our group is not yet familiar with programming in general. Thank you so much for your help!